# i am getting html response from server but image tag doesnt work

Tags: android, android-imageview

hi i am developing one android app,where i am showing comment releated to that ticket.but on server side database  all comment are stored in html format.when i send request for it i get all html code.But i managed to convert HTML code in proper format by using

```
  comm.setText(Html.fromHtml(cmnt[position]));
```

But the problem is that if there is image tag in comment then it will show small box instead of image.i want to display that image proprely.
please help me

Single_Ticket.java

```
 private class showcomment extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    ProgressDialog pdialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.v("TAG", "In onPreExecute of the loading comnt.");



    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            Log.v("TAG", "In doInBackground of the loading comment. ");

            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tktid", id));
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();


            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URL_COMMENT, ServiceHandler.POST, param);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null)

            {
                try {

                    contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    int a=contacts.length();
                    Log.v(TAG, ".................." + a);
                    if(a > 0 ) {
                       cmnt = new String[contacts.length()];
                        cmnt_time = new String[contacts.length()];
                        cmnt_by = new String[contacts.length()];
                        for (int i = (a-1),j=0; i >= 0&& j < contacts.length(); i--,j++) {

                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(j);
                            Log.v(TAG, "" + i);
                            String aa = c.getString("cmnt");
                            String bb = c.getString("cmnt_time");
                            String cc = c.getString("cmnt_by");

                            Log.v(TAG,""+aa);
                            cmnt[i] = aa;
                            cmnt_time[i]=bb;
                            cmnt_by[i]=cc;
                            Log.v(TAG,""+cmnt[i]);
                        }


                        }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.print("hiiiiiiiiiiii" );
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if(cmnt!=null && cmnt.length > 0 ) {
           C_adapter adapter = new C_adapter(Single_Ticket.this, cmnt,cmnt_by,cmnt_time);
            cmntview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

C_adapter.java

```
public class C_adapter extends ArrayAdapter   {

Context context;
String[] cmnt;
String[] cmnt_by;
String[] cmnt_time;
LayoutInflater inflater;


public C_adapter(Single_Ticket context, String[] cmnt,String[] cmnt_by,String[] cmnt_time) {
    super(context, R.id.cmnt_list,cmnt);
    this.context=context;
    this.cmnt=cmnt;
    this.cmnt_by=cmnt_by;
    this.cmnt_time=cmnt_time;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cmnt_list, null);

    }
    TextView comm = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmnt);
    TextView cmntby = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmntby);

    comm.setText(Html.fromHtml(cmnt[position]));
    if(cmnt_by[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Lalit Patil")|| cmnt_by[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Sarvesh Sonawane"))
    {
        //cmntby.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange_red);
        cmntby.setText(cmnt_time[position]+" - "+cmnt_by[position]);

    }
    cmntby.setText(cmnt_time[position]+" - "+cmnt_by[position]);

    return convertView;
}



   }
```

I got response from server like this

```
{"cmnt":"<img src=\"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/JHcdBVj.jpg\" width=\"448\"><br>","cmnt_time":"Wed,07 Oct 2015 05:41pm","cmnt_by":"test test"}
```

Comment: Image Tag will not work in TextView. You should use WebView instead of TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Place ***ImageView*** and ***TextView*** on the same position in your ***layout.xml*** file.

Then check the content of your data which you get from server and if the data have ***img*** tag then ***set visible to image view and set the Bitmap to image view*** otherwise ***set visible to text view***.

I have made a function for you. I am using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to set the image in image view, ***using Picasso we can set image in image view with just 1 line.***

```
public void setImage() {
        try {
            String response = "{\"cmnt\":\"<img src=\\\"http:\\/\\/i.imgur.com\\/JHcdBVj.jpg\\\" width=\\\"448\\\"><br>\",\"cmnt_time\":\"Wed,07 Oct 2015 05:41pm\",\"cmnt_by\":\"test test\"}";

            JSONObject jsonresponse = new JSONObject(response);
            String cmnt = jsonresponse.getString("cmnt");
            if (cmnt.contains("<img")) {
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(cmnt);
                if (m.find()) {
                    cmnt = m.group(1);
                }
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(cmnt)
                        .into(imageView);
            } else {
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```